# How to adjust ratings of N items by pairwise comparisons

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-comparisons, ranking, nonparametric, bradley-terry-model

I have been keeping a list of movies I've seen in a spreadsheet and assigning them numerical rankings that approximate how I feel about them. A few years ago I implemented a program to read in the data and allow me to make pairwise comparisons and adjust numerical scores by the Elo rating system. I quickly realized this wasn't going to converge because N choose 2 is too large.

I have skimmed a few papers and gotten a sense that this may have something to do with Bradley-Terry-Luce models, but I am not sure such models or the algorithms built on them leverage and adjust the ratings I already have. I am also not sure they incorporate new datapoints well.

Here is a naive idea: Think of each movie as an isolated node in a graph containing a number corresponding to its score. When a comparison is made, add an edge and readjust the numbers on each side of that new edge by some amount. Then propagate that change outward along existing edges of the graph, presumably decaying it by some rate and stopping when the change is near enough zero.

Is there a more appropriate algorithm that is simple and well-suited to this problem from the statistical signal processing literature?